# Using Regex to Scrape Text

Tags: python, regex

Here is my code so far that i'm having trouble matching text before "v." and some other terms.

```
(?s)v\..*?(?:\d\d\d\d\))
```

Sample Text:

```
See Holiday in v. Marriot (2002)

e.g. FB v. Google (2012)

; Yahoo! v. Microsoft (2000)"
```

I need to be about to grab:

```
Holiday in v. Marriot (2002)

FB v. Google (2012)
 
Yahoo! v. Microsoft (2000)
```

Comment: How would you split before "Holiday in", "FB" and "Yahoo!" ? What about an input like `I.B.M. v. H.A.L (2001)` ?

Comment: Is it a single multiline text? What did you try to do with that pattern of yours? What are the match requirements?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/HiH6iq/1) will fit.

Comment: Unless you can list all the possible noise words to skip, this is a natural-language processing problem. You can't do AI with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only single uppercase words, you could start with an uppercase char followed by dots or other uppercase chars and then any char except uppercase chars till `v.`

```
(?s)\b[A-Z][A-Z.]*[^A-Z]*v\..*?\(\d{4}\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DeSsgh/1)

Another option could be specifying the possible leading chars using an alternation `|` with a capture group:

```
(?s)(?:\bSee\b|\be\.g\.|;)\s*(.*?\s+v\..*?\(\d{4}\))
```

- `(?s)` Inline modifier to have the dot match a newline
- `(?:\bSee\b|\be\.g\.|;)` Match one of the alternatives
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*?\s+v\.` Match as least as possible chars and then `v.`
  - `.*?\(\d{4}\)` Match as least as possible chars and then 4 digits between parenthesis
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNHKVq/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
See\s+(.*)\s+\S+\s+(.*)\s+;\s+(.*)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/X37l9z/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  See                      'See'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```